# Div doesn't scale to 100% of parent but to 100% of viewport

Tags: html, css

I want the image on the left of the table to scale to 100% of the table height. But this doesn't happen, it scales to the viewport, if I make my browser windows less tall the image scales down to fit. Isn't the height-property supposed to scale to the size of the parent element? I can't follow why this is happening.

```css
#specieslist {
 display: inline;
    font-size: 16pt;
    line-height: 2em;

}

#abundancenumber {
    color: transparent;
}

#abundancenumber:hover {
    color: black;
}

#tree{
    height: 100%;
    white-space: normal;

 }

#treecontainer{
    height: 100%;
    align: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

#tablecontainer{
    display : inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: normal;

}

#container{
    white-space: nowrap;
}

h1 {
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

 color: green;
 display: block;
 font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: bold;

    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}

p, ul {
    font-family: medium-content-serif-font,Georgia,Cambria,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    line-height: 2em;

    width:60%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;

}


.occurrencecell1, .occurrencecell0 {
    color: transparent;
}


.occurrencecell1{
    background-color: red;
}



.rTable { display: table; }
.rTableRow { display: table-row; }
.rTableHeading {
    display: table-header-group;
    font-weight: 700
}
.rTableBody { display: table-row-group; }
.rTableFoot { display: table-footer-group; }
.rTableCell {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 3em;
    #font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-family: medium-content-serif-font,Georgia,Cambria,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
}

.rTableHead {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 8em;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre-wrap

    font-family: medium-content-sans-serif-font, "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Geneva, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>

<div id="container">




<body>

<p>Here comes the table.</p>


<div id="treecontainer">

    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c4/PSM_V18_D630_Restoration_of_a_lepidodendron.jpg/170px-PSM_V18_D630_Restoration_of_a_lepidodendron.jpg" id="tree" alt="here is the tree">

</div>


 <div id="tablecontainer">

<div class="rTable">


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
            
            <div class="rTablehead">Most precise classification</div>
            
            <div class="rTablehead">Abundance sample 1</div>
            
            <div class="rTablehead">Acetaldehyde dehydrogenase, acetylating, (EC 1.2.1.10) in gene cluster for degradation of phenols, cresols, catechol
</div>
            
            <div class="rTablehead">Fumarylacetoacetate hydrolase family protein
</div>
            
            <div class="rTablehead">Intradiol ring-cleavage dioxygenase (EC 1.13.11.1)
</div>
            

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Genus;Sulfuricurvum</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 251)">0.994935871505</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>



    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Species;Sulfuritalea hydrogenivorans</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.462437387974</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Species;Rugosibacter aromaticivorans</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.561122358435</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Species;Rugosibacter aromaticivorans</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.577384533061</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Species;Rugosibacter aromaticivorans</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.545778859496</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Species;Rugosibacter aromaticivorans</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.545779954269</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Genus;Acidovorax</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.430993166758</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Species;Acidovorax sp. JHL-3</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.298164873689</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Species;Acidovorax sp. JHL-3</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.275778021248</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Species;Acidovorax sp. JHL-3</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.251830098492</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Family;Comamonadaceae</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.452451191222</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Family;Comamonadaceae</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.511172699188</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Family;Comamonadaceae</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.490082090254</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Family;Comamonadaceae</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.478207414014</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Family;Comamonadaceae</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.502823943285</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Family;Comamonadaceae</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.470744436736</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Order;Burkholderiales</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.532271142742</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Order;Burkholderiales</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.535328291754</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Order;Burkholderiales</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.529046132699</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Order;Burkholderiales</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.544876275234</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Order;Burkholderiales</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.563369894866</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Order;Burkholderiales</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.549781260553</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Species;Burkholderiales bacterium RIFOXYC12_FULL_65_23</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(10, 0, 0)">-0.48417394392</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell1">1</div>
            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>


    <div class="rTableRow">

        
        <div class="rTableCell">Genus;Sulfuricurvum</div>
        <div class="rTableCell" id="abundancenumber" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255)">1.0</div>

        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

            
                <div class="rTableCell occurrencecell0">nan</div>

            


        

        




    </div>



</div>
 </div>








</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong with your code, starting from formatting and ending with simulating `tables` using `divs` when there really is no need for such.

To answer your question, child elements can reference the height of a parent element as long as the height of the parent element is available when the child element tries to use it. Since the parent element's height is not explicitly defined, it is calculated after laying out all child elements, including the image, and as such, it is not available when the image needs to use it.

Here are a couple of things you can look into:

- use CSS3 `flexbox` to lay out the `image` and the `#tablecontainer`. You can find a quick tutorial for it here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/
- use `position: absolute` on the `image` and `position: relative` on the `#container`. Absolutely positioning an element removes it from the regular layout flow and allows you to use the parent's calculated height. You will also need to add additional padding on the left side of the `#tablecontainer`, should you choose to go this route (since the image will be tehnically overlayed).
- set the image as a background for the `#container` and use `background-size: contain` and `background-position` to adjust it's location. As above, you will need to add additional padding on the left side of the `#tablecontainer`. One way you can do this is set `padding-left`.

Comment: thanks for your help, I'm currently implementing the flexbox solution. But isn't the layout constantly updated? if my viewport scales, my image scales, then why doesn't my image scale when one of the divs changes size?

Comment: also how should I do this layout using flex? I set to container to display: inline-flex, removed the %-height from the image, and now it works. is this ok?